# Weekly meetings with boss are not happening

Tags: management

My boss does not meet with me on a weekly basis like she does with the rest of her staff. Do I wait for her to initiate weekly meetings or do I make it happen?

Comment: Do you know what the topic of these weekly meetings would be?

Comment: What is your occupation?

Answer (score 5):

> Do I wait for her to initiate weekly meetings or do I make it happen?

In your situation, I would suggest **you ask your boss how they feel about a bi-weekly meeting to review your work and any other concerns they may have**.  If they agree, set them up and adjust the frequency as necessary.

I would urge you to end every one of those meetings with something along the lines of "*Are there any issues I should be aware of or any opportunities of improvement?*"  You should always ask for the feedback, and the sooner you get it the quicker you can course correct if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a meeting or regular meetings, just ask. Make your professional needs known or else they won't ever be satisfied.

However, don't ask for a meeting just because everyone else has one. You would look really silly if your meeting goes:

Boss: So, what did you want to talk about.

JLemish: Uhhh..... I don't know. Everyone else has weekly meetings, so I thought I should too.

Comment: She has one-on-ones with everyone to make sure they are "on track". One just received a promotion. I wonder if she is not meeting with me because she doesn't want to provide a positive review. Better to not know...

Comment: If you're already convinced you're not getting meetings because you're incompetent and being fired is imminent, why ask the question? I generally advise against making wild assumptions about other people's potential motivations. If you want to regularly check-in with your boss and see how you're progressing, get necessary feedback, etc do it. If you want to live in constant fear of getting fired because you're not asking for or receiving any feedback, so you assume everyone hates you and wants you gone, keep doing what you're doing.

Comment: @JLemish, far better to know if things are not positive while you still have a chance to fix whatever is wrong.